# dropzone.js + paperclip uploading each image as its own post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, dropzone.js

I am facing a strange issue.

I have `Post has_many attachments. as: :imageable`

and
 `Attachment belongs_to imageable, polymorphic: true`

I am trying to upload multiple images attached to a single post using dropzone.js

However, whenever I upload multiple files in the dropzone-powered form, each image gets uploaded as its own post. I upload 4 images, I get 4 posts with each of the attached image.
How can I get all of the images I attach to a post to be associated with that post only?

Here is what the `posts.js` looks like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  // disable auto discover
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

 // grap our upload form by its id
 $("#new_post").dropzone({

 // restrict image size to a maximum 1MB
 maxFilesize: 1,

 // changed the passed param to one accepted by
 // our rails app

 paramName: "post[attachments_attributes][][picture]",
 // show remove links on each image upload
 addRemoveLinks: true
  });
});
```

Create action from the `PostsController`

```
def create
@post = Post.create(post_params)


if @post.save
  render json: { message: "success" }, :status => 200
else
  #  you need to send an error header, otherwise Dropzone
      #  will not interpret the response as an error:
  render json: { error: @post.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
end

end
```

Relevant section of the `_form.html.erb` for the `new` Post action:

```
<%= form_for(@post, html: {class:"dropzone"}) do |f| %>
....
<div class="fallback">
<%= f.label :attachments %>
 <%= f.fields_for :attachments  do |at| %>
   <%= at.file_field :picture %>
 <% end %>
</div>
....
<% end %>
```

The param name is `post[attachment_attributes][0][picture]` as it appears in the form HTML.
I suspect that this is the cause for the issue, but how do I change it so that the request uploads all the images attached to one post?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at the dev log, I realized that each file dragged into dropzone file field submits a new request and saves it to the database as a post without title and body (because I had validations turned off) I have to make changes to dropzone.js to combine all requests into one.

Answer (score 0):

[Dropzone Issue](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/181) It looks like this is an issue that is untested but you can use the development branch of Dropzone to access it. This link has the details.